# How To Deal With "." in the middle of a program name In a bat File?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I need to check with a bat file if a program is running in tasksheduler.

The big problem is this program is from external guys and have four "." in the middle of the name.

I'm using this code :

```
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe">NUL
msg * %ERRORLEVEL%
goto Exit
```

with program running behind I was expecting the return of errorlevel 0 , but it is returning 1

I believe the problem is this "." in the name of the program.

Comment: Why do you you think the problem is caused by `.`? I just tried this with `NVDisplay.Container.exe` (two periods) and errorlevel is set to 0 as expected. Did you try with a different executable and did that work? What is the output of just the tasklist command?

Comment: i try this with other programs that dont have a dot in the midle and it work, i was assuming the problem das the dot in the midle of the name ! the ideia of this was to avoid an user open more than an instance of a program, of course i need to add if error is zero dont do anything , if is 1 open the program, but since was not working i test only to see the output , but always return 1 :(

Comment: Are you sure this executable is actually running? Did you double check for typos?

Comment: i'm new on code !! this is because a guy open a lot of windows and then the other guys dont have licences to open, i was trying to limit this guy to only open 1 instance of this program

Comment: if the program was a notepad app the code was :                                                                                     tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "notepad.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
msg * "Programa ja aberto!!"
goto Exit
)
else if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
cd "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
start notepad.exe  
goto Exit
)                                                                                                                            this code works for program without dot in the name, " Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe " not work ! :(

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You do not have to worry about how to deal with **`.`**, this is not the cause of this problem here, this only is about length characters length in `tasklist` output.

See `tasklist` for command `tasklist | find /i /n "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe"`
should result in:

```bat
[263]Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe     8900 Console                    1      4,076 K
```

But that is never going to happen, the output from `tasklist` are using precisely **25 characters length for names** in, and you are trying find with one string that **have 28 characters length** `tasklist | find /i /n "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe"`, so, you will never get the desire result using this string with 28 characters length:

Try smaller with 25 characters in string:

```bat
tasklist | find /i /n "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell."
```

You will forever get this output without `exe`:

```bat
[263]Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.     8900 Console                    1      4,076 K
```

Some suggest code:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

tasklist | find /I /N "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell." >NUL && (
%__APPDIR__%msg.exe * !errorlevel! zOk, here i'm! & goto Exit:
)|| %__APPDIR__%msg.exe * !errorlevel! nOp, I'm not there! & goto Exit:
   
:Exit:
endlocal
```

---

To use the full name in your running query process, try with `wmic`

```bat
wmic process where name="Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" get processid /value 
wmic process where name="Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" get caption /value
wmic process where name="Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" get name /value
```

- Use:

```bat
wmic process where name="Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" get name | find /v "Name"
```

- Output:

```bat
Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe
```

- Get full list descriptions listed:

```bat
wmic process where name="Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" get * /format:list
```

- Results:

```bat
Caption=Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe
CommandLine="C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\"Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe"
CreationClassName=Win32_Process
CreationDate=20200423222440.079263-180
CSCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
CSName=LAME_SLUG
Description=Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe
ExecutablePath=C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp\Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe
ExecutionState=
Handle=12752
HandleCount=79
InstallDate=
KernelModeTime=312500
MaximumWorkingSetSize=1380
MinimumWorkingSetSize=200
Name=Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe
OSCreationClassName=Win32_OperatingSystem
OSName=Microsoft Windows 10 Pro|C:\Windows|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4
OtherOperationCount=1505
OtherTransferCount=29348
PageFaults=2228
PageFileUsage=2624
ParentProcessId=11868
PeakPageFileUsage=4236
PeakVirtualSize=2203379519488
PeakWorkingSetSize=4288
Priority=8
PrivatePageCount=2686976
ProcessId=12752
QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage=6
QuotaPagedPoolUsage=46
QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage=6
QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage=46
ReadOperationCount=14
ReadTransferCount=822
SessionId=1
Status=
TerminationDate=
ThreadCount=1
UserModeTime=0
VirtualSize=2203378040832
WindowsVersion=10.0.18363
WorkingSetSize=4255744
WriteOperationCount=0
WriteTransferCount=0
```

- Some further reading:

[√] **[wmic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)**

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating the command. This would be enough and work better:

```
tasklist | find /I /N "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe">NUL
```

Comment: While usefull, this doesn't look like it's an answer to the question

Comment: @Berend: "I need to check with a bat file if a program is running in taskshedule".

Comment: I read the problem as "Why is errorlevel set to 1 instead of 0?"

Comment: i will try give me some moments

Comment: it still is returning 1 :(

Comment: It is returning `0` for me. Your batch file must be in error.

Comment: Or perhaps this process is executing in elevated mode while yours is not. Try to run CMD as Admin to test.