# How to detect that a Windows application is running (no GUI)

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

Would like to have a suggestion on how to detect (preferably in such a way a batch file could use the result) whether a certain application is running so that some action could be taken.
(Of course, not something GUI-based).

Comment: [Tasklist - Display all running applications - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) and [PsList - List detailed information about processes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pslist.html)

Comment: Hi, could you please let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 2):

```bath
@echo off 

set "_results=Not Running"
set "_imagename=executable_with_imagename_length_greater_than_25_characters.exe"
tasklist.exe /svc /fo list | find.exe /i "%_imagename%" >nul && set "_results=%_results:Not =%"

echo=%_results%
```

- Use: **`Tasklist /svc /fo list`**
- Use: **`Find "string" && [if/because return 0 do()] || [if/because return non 0 do()]`**

---

[image]

---

Notice something in this scenario

1. I have one executable running
2. The name +(.extension) of my executable has more them 25 characters in length
3. Using `TaskList/fi "imagename eq some_imagename.exe"`, has a 25 character limitation where `imagename.exe` will appear
4. Using `TaskList/fi "imagename eq some_imagename.exe"|find "some_imagename.exe"` return `errorlevel == 0`
5. But using the command below, I always get `errorlevel == 1`, due to the limitation of characters in the `imagename` field

---

To obtain accurate information, not limited to character length, replace:

```bath
tasklist /fi "imagename eq executable_with_imagename_length_greater_than_25_characters.exe"|find /i "executable_with_imagename_length_greater_than_25_characters.exe"

Tasklist /svc /fo list | find /i "executable_with_imagename_length_greater_than_25_characters.exe"
```

---

- What these commands are doing

```bath
   Inhibits echo on commands:  @echo off  

Define status to Not Running:  set "_results=Not Running   
Define The Program.eXtension:  set "_imagename=executable.exe"

                    TaskList:  tasklist.exe /svc /fo list 
                               /SVC  Displays services hosted in each process.
                               /FO   format  Specifies the output format.
                                             Valid values: "TABLE", "LIST", "CSV".

Redirect TaskLis out to Find:   tasklist.exe ... | find ...

 Handles input "%filtering%":   find.exe /i "%_imagename%" 

     Omit find output/string:   >nul

  if command returned 0 runs:   && next_cmd

Replace/Remove 'Not ' in var:   set "_results=%_results:Not =%"

Echoes the current condition:   echo=%_results%
```

---

- This is all intended to explain that the use of TaskList with the flag `"/fi "imagename eq executable"` is not accurate/reliable, without considering the character string containing the name.eXtension of file/program:

---

```bath
@echo off 

set "_results=Not Running"
set "_imagename=executable.exe"
tasklist.exe /svc /fo list|find.exe /i "%_imagename%">nul && set "_results=%_results:Not =%"

echo=%_results%
```

---

- A simple alternative would be:

```bath
@echo off 

tasklist.exe /svc /fo list | ( 
     find.exe /i "Program_Name.exe" 
   ) >nul && echo;True || echo;False
```

---

- What I would use:

```bath
@echo off

for /f %%i in ('"tasklist.exe /svc /fo list|find.exe /i "ProgramName.Exe">nul && echo;True||echo;False"
')do set "_bool=%%~i"
   
echo/%_bool%
```

---

> *preferably in such a way a batch file could use the result*

- Using argument's:

```bath
file.cmd program.exe outvar
```

```bath
@echo off

if "%~1" == "" (set "_default=My_Default_Program.exe") else set "_default=%~nx1"
for /f %%i in ('"tasklist.exe /svc /fo list|find.exe /i "%_default%">nul && echo;True||echo;False"
')do set "_bool=%%~i" && set "%~2=%%~i"
 

echo/%_bool%
```

- :: Or using `:lable`....

```bath
@echo off

for /f %%i in ('"tasklist.exe /svc /fo list|find.exe /i "%~1">nul && echo;True||echo;False"
')do if "%%~i" == "True" goto :True_Label_Job

echo/%~nx1 False
rem :: command for False condition here...
rem :: command for False condition here... 
rem :: command for False condition here... 
exit /b || goto :eof

:True_Label_Job
echo/%~nx1 True
rem :: command for True condition here...
rem :: command for True condition here... 
rem :: command for True condition here... 
exit /b || goto :eof
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Tasklist /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [Variable and Substring Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)
- [Command line parameters in batch file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)
- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

---

- ***[Another answer dealing with the same point addressed but with a different title](https://superuser.com/a/1545152/969781)***

  - ***[How To Deal With “.” in the middle of a program name In a bat File?](https://superuser.com/a/1545152/969781)***

> *I need to check with a bat file if a program is running in tasksheduler.*
>
> *The big problem is this program is from external guys and have four `"."`*
> *in the middle of the name.*
>
> *I'm using this code:*
>
> ```bath
> tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Fls.Core.Portal.UI.Shell.exe">NUL
> msg * %ERRORLEVEL%
> goto Exit
> ```
>
> *with program running behind I was expecting the return of*
> *`errorlevel 0`, but it is returning `1`*
>
> *I believe the problem is this `"."` in the name of the program.*

---

Answer (score 1):

The
[tasklist command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist)
can search for a given process.

Checking for success inside a batch file is a bit complicated, since
this command does not set the `errorlevel`.

You need then to use it in conjunction with another utility that does set it,
for example the
[find command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find)
like this:

```
echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find "notepad.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 0 echo I found notepad.exe
```

The idea here is that `notepad.exe` will appear in the output only if
the task is found, hence `find` will set the errorlevel to `0` for `found`
and `1` for `not found`.

See also:

- [if command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if)
- [Errorlevel and Exit codes](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)